# RISC-V - trap handler with a separate stack

Tags: assembly, gcc, riscv, interrupt-handling

I need to implement a machine mode trap handler on a bare-metal RISC-V system. The trap handler should be using a separate stack region from the main program. I understand the basic flow for that if implementing in assembly:

1. enter the trap handler
2. write `sp` with the trap stack pointer (saved in `mscratch` for example)
3. save the context on the stack (registers x1-x31)
4. do stuff
5. restore the context from the stack
6. write sp with the original stack pointer
7. return with `mret`

Now, I am trying to minimize the use of assembly code, and looking at the [GCC's RISC-V specific function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/RISC-V-Function-Attributes.html#RISC-V-Function-Attributes):

```
void f (void) __attribute__ ((interrupt ("machine")));
```

It looks like it is capable of doing all of the steps above automagically *except* steps 2 and 6 - that is swapping stacks.
The question - is there a way/trick in GCC to make a function, that is an interrupt handler - for context saving or a general function for stack frame allocation to use a different stack?

(Note: I am aware of the `naked` attribute, but the idea here is to benefit from the automatic generation of prologue/epilogue the `interrupt` attribute is providing)

**UPD:** I have actually found that in recent SiFive specific GCC they have introduced the extra attribute options:

```
void f (void) __attribute__ ((interrupt ("SiFive-CLIC-stack-swap")));
```

as can be seen in their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sifive/riscv-gcc/blob/sifive-gcc-10.2.0/gcc/config/riscv/riscv.c#L5879)
But it looks like it is only done for machine traps. I am looking for a solution that would work similarly for supervisor traps as well.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're focused on using GCC features to avoid or minimize assembly. 
Inline assembly in C, mixing assembly operations with C code, can have a higher learning curve than pure assembly (plus pure C alone).

Comment: @ErikEidt Perhaps you are right. I am starting to get to a similar conclusion, that separating the assembly from C looks cleaner and clearer, and I'll probably go with it. Still, this gcc feature seems incomplete, and it would be nice to have it implemented properly.